# Art, image creation using hand and software

Tags: adobe-illustrator, software-recommendation, adobe-after-effects, adobe-draw, technical-drawing

In several youtube links I didn't find a guide on how charts make figures of this kind. Surely it could be `Adobe Illustrator`, the first candidate but surely it could be some other program. To create, for example, a golf man thus more perfect what are the steps?

I would to say what are the instruments that a graphic designer who has to draw such an image.

I don't want someone to draw the image for me but to understand the tools and how to proceed to learn.

[image]

Comment: Sorry.. what's the question? How to draw the golfer? That image is most likely not using any canned "chart creation" feature anywhere. The short answer is *you draw the chart and images associated with it*. There is a reason being an artist is a profession. If computers could do it all with a couple clicks, all artists would be out of work.

Comment: @Scott I have improved my question and I'm sorry for 2 downvotes. I don't want the image to be reproduced by anyone but to understand how to draw and what better tools to use between them. Often if I don't do the translation with Deepl I don't understand your answer. Very sorry.

Comment: Learning to draw, for those which aren't naturally inclined, can be a lengthy process. And a simple Q and A web site is not thorough enough to explain "how to draw". Software choice comes down to one's own style and/or aptitude as well as desired output. Sorry. I think this is now far too broad. There are courses, books, web sites, etc. dedicated to teaching how to draw in specific applications.

Comment: @Scott Thanks. I am very sad when i received 2 downvotes. My question was also to understand how I must study this matter. All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The starting point is to become aware how the golf club, player's hands, feet, head and body should be placed. One good idea is to get some photos which present real players.

Then you should draw the player as a stick figure - do it with the pen on a paper. His head should have at least eyes and nose to show how the head is oriented. Find the right limb angles including the feet and right body curvature. When the stick figure looks right you can insert some thickness. Do not try to draw it in a computer until you get it right on paper. It can be very rudimentary but it must look a golf player just hitting.

There are numerous "Draw a golf player" tutorials in the web. Some of them show how an artist work. One example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1G0L3YdOUwo That guy obviously knows well how a golfer acts. He can imagine it, he doesn't have to extract it from a photo. In addition he probably has practiced drawing say 50 years.

Inkscape is very good vector drawing program for simple images. You can draw with the bezier curve tool ("the pen") by clicking. Edit with the node tool and insert fills and strokes as needed. Work some tutorials, the web is full of them.

Inkscape has one trap. Manual tracing with the pen is so easy that you can copy the essence of a player photo in the day 1. Only import or paste a photo on the artboard and lock it in the objects panel to prevent it moving. The trap is that you forget to learn to draw it by yourself.

ADD: There's in a comment something that must be known. It's not especially difficult to make an exact copy of a simple drawing like the player in your example. A copy is a copy, no matter you have drawn it or used a copy machine. It's still copied (=a derivative work) if you change a part of things.  A drawing based on a photo can also be seen as a copy. There's no predeclared measure how much it can legally resemble the original.

One way to avoid copyright and drawing problems is to purchase an image. Theoretically it's possible a suitable image is included in a free clipart collection. Read the license before using a downloaded image. If there's no explicit license that says this is free, it very likely isn't free. Using
some free images needs you include also the name of the artist.

Using clipart is not free of artistic difficulties. Making an acceptable composition is still a challenge (colors, placements, fitting into the wanted mood)

Comment: The trap may be copyright infringement as well. `:)`

Comment: Ok. I inserted it.

Comment: @user287001 Thank you always for your kindness...+1...I have improved my question. Now is it more clear? What is the significance of "The trap may be copyright infringement as well."?

Comment: @user287001 I'm watching the video....:-). Hence before it is necessary to draw with the hand and to make a scan of the manual reproduction?...After I can use a tool or I can draw directly using a software. Do you, please, improved my question?

Comment: At least in western countries images belong to someone, The creator can be that someone or another person or a  company if the creator has sold or otherwise given the the copyright out of his hands. The copyright owner determines how much the usage of the image costs. In many countries the law states a time how old an image must be to be free (=be in public domain). The problem exists only if you are going to sell, show to others or give for free something. In theory a copyright infringement can cost you plenty of money + irreversible loss of reputation. Impossible to calculate beforehand.

Comment: @user287001 I have not a designer as you can see from the profile, but I was curious how to draw with tools. Could you please insert, for example, how to create an ear with hair through an animation? What are the most suitable tools? Adobe or others that need to be crossed?

Comment: I said keep out of a drawing program to become able to draw. Its very much an ability to see the wanted figure inside one's head. When you know what to draw you can use directly a drawing program. Before it practice the program  tricks separately. Having at the same time a must to create something and find how to make lines and curves leads to a mess. I have seen artist drawing pencil sketches, scanning them and making the final job in a computer. They said: The computer is too stiff, it is a brake for the creative work.

Comment: It's not a mechanism to draw an ear. Drawing lines and curves and spreading colors are mechanical. The whole trick is to see which lines, curves and colors you need for an ear. Learn to draw complex forms. then try to copy an ear, hair etc... of an existing drawing (=draw over). Then you can learn a way to see which shapes are needed.

Comment: @Sebastiano The most suitable tool for a start is a pencil + a piece of paper. Use a slightly transparent paper try to practice by copying. Have a cartoon under it. Then repeat by keeping the original aside. Finally have no original. Have a parallel show of practicing to draw lines, curves and colored areas and deforming them manageably in the computer. Get Inkscape or Illustrator. Inkscape costs EUR0,00. The next Inkscape example shows how to proceed when one knows the needed shapes and knows how to make shapes he wants (needs both skills) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDN406oZ_3s

Comment: @user287001 Impressive. The designer is ver very fast......:-) I accept you answer and I wish to you my always thank you...biggest.